# How can I enable a user from a different AAD tenant to access vsts package feeds?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-artifacts

I have a private package feed in my VTST tenant.

I want to expose this feed to a person from another organization with a different AAD tenant.

I tried adding the person in the package read permissions, but i'm getting `no identities found` error for his email.

Can I achieve this using VSTS?

Comment: You may need to add the user to a project in VSTS first. That will bring their identity into your VSTS account (tenant) so that it can then be found in the package read identity picker.

Comment: You need to add the user to your vsts, then you can add the user to package feed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the user to your VSTS `https://[account].visualstudio.com/_admin/_users`, then you can add it to the package feed.

If your VSTS is backed by AAD (Team Services: [Access with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/manage-organization-access-for-your-account-vs)), you need to add that user to your AAD, check the Q&A: [Why can't I add users from other directories to my Azure AD?](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/manage-organization-access-for-your-account-vs#add-users-to-directory)

Otherwise, you can add the user to your VSTS directly.

Comment: won't adding the user to my vsts give him permission to my code? I just want him to have permission to the packages...

Comment: You need to add user to your AAD (could be guest user).